# Telerik MVC Grid Events Edit / Add

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I want to call different functions for the edit and for the create command in a grid. In my Grid i added a command for editing

```
command.Edit().Text(" ").UpdateText("Speichern").CancelText("Abbrechen");
```

and i have a toolbar which does the create

```
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Hinzufügen")).
```

On the Events i have

```
.Events(e => {e.Edit("onEdit");})
```

the function onEdit is called by the create and the edit command...
My question now is...

Is there any way to have a own Event/function for the create command?

Answer (score 0):

You can add events for Item created and Item Edited this way:

In your .aspx

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="yourTableId"
    OnItemCreated="yourTableIdl_ItemCreated"
    OnEditCommand="yourTableId_ItemCommand"
    ... />
```

In your code-behind (.aspx.cs)

```
protected void yourTableId_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}

protected void yourTableId_EditCommand(object sender, GridEditEventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

There is many more "On" events that are usefull like OnCommandItem.

Hope this is what you were looking for.